# Change of basis associated to several successive rotations

Tags: rotations, change-of-basis

Let us consider vector bases $\mathcal{B_0} = (a,b,c)$, $\mathcal{B_1} = (i,j,k) $ and $\mathcal{B_2} = (x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, such that :

- $\mathcal{B_1}$ is obtained by applying a rotation, defined by the matrix $R_1$, to $\mathcal{B_0}$
- $\mathcal{B_2}$ is obtained by applying a rotation, defined by the matrix $R_2$, to $\mathcal{B_1}$

So we have :

- $i = R_1 a$, $j = R_1 b$ and $k = R_1 c$
- $x = R_2 i = R_2 R_1 a$, $y = R_2 j = R_2 R_1 b$ and $z = R_2 k = R_2 R_1 c$

Thus, the two successive rotations can be directly described by just one matrix $R_3 = R_2 R_1$.

Now, introduce a vector $\mathbf{v}$, expressed as $\mathbf{v}_0$ in $\mathcal{B_0}$, $\mathbf{v}_1$ in $\mathcal{B_1}$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ in $\mathcal{B_2}$.

By definition of a rotation matrix, the changes of basis from $\mathcal{B_0}$ to $\mathcal{B_1}$, and from $\mathcal{B_1}$ to $\mathcal{B_2}$ are expressed as :

- $v_0 = R_1 v_1$
- $v_1 = R_2 v_2$

So we have : $v_0 = R_1 R_2 v_2 = P_0^2 v_ 2$, where $P_0^2$ allows to change from basis $\mathcal{B_2}$ to basis $\mathcal{B_1}$.

So, if we take $v = x$, we have $x_2 = [1, 0, 0]^T$ and $x_0 = R_2 R_1 a_0$.

Since $a_0 = [1, 0, 0]^T = x_2$ $\implies$ $x_0 = R_2 R_1 x_2$ which is (obviously) different from $x_0 = R_1 R_2 x_2$

By definition of a rotation matrix, we should have $P_0^2 = R_3$, as for Euler angles rotation matrix. However the last line implies  $P_0^2 \neq R_3$ as matrix product is not commutative. So where is the problem in my development ? Is it just that we do not compose change of basis like rotations ?

Comment: "So, if we take $v = x$, we have $x_2 = [1, 0, 0]^T$ and $x_0 = R_2 R_1 a_0$." Where does $x_0 = R_2 R_1 a_0$ come from?

Comment: It cames from the definition of the basis $\mathcal{B}_2$ vectors: $x$ expressed in $\mathcal{B}_0$ (noted $x_0$) is obtained by the two successive rotations $R_1$ and $R_2$ applied on $a$ also expressed in $\mathcal{B}_0$ (noted $a_0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a general problem: we have a basis $\mathcal{B}_0$ and a basis $\mathcal{B}_1$ and we want to get the coordinate matrix of the transformation $[\mathrm{Id}]_{1}^{0}$, so the transformation that takes coordinate vectors in $\mathcal{B}_0$ and takes it to $\mathcal{B}_1$. Let $x_i,y_i$ be the basis vectors of $\mathcal{B}_0,\mathcal{B}_1$ and suppose $P$ is a linear transformation such that $Px_i=y_i$. Let $[v]_{0/1}$ denote the coordinate vector of $v$ in $\mathcal{B}_{0/1}$ respectively.

Now let's define $[P]_0^0$ by saying that it takes $[v]_0$ to $[Pv]_0$ - this is achieved by setting the columns of $[P]_0^0$ to be $[Px_i]_0=[y_i]_0$. Therefore, this matrix takes $[y_i]_1$ to $[Px_i]_0=[y_i]_0$ so in fact $[P]_0^0=[\mathrm{Id}]_{0}^{1}=([\mathrm{Id}]_{1}^{0})^{-1}$.

In your case $P$ is a rotation. I think that basically the problem is that you never defined in which bases you're looking at $R_1$, $R_2$: are we talking $[R_1]^0_0$ or $[R_1]^1_1$ or $[R_1]_2^0$ or what? And the answer then depends. I presume you meant $[R_1]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_1^1$, in which case $$
[x]_0=[\mathrm{Id}]_{0}^{1}[\mathrm{Id}]_{1}^{2}[x]_2=[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1[x]_2
$$
and also
$$
[x]_2=[a]_0=[R_1^{-1}]_0^0[R_2^{-1}]_0^0[x]_0=([R_1]^0_0){-1}[\mathrm{Id}]_{0}^{1}[R_2^{-1}]_1^1[\mathrm{Id}]_{1}^{0}[x]_0=([R_1]^0_0)^{-1}[R_1]^0_0[R_2^{-1}]_1^1([R_1]^0_0)^{-1}[x]_0=([R_2]_1^1)^{-1}([R_1]^0_0)^{-1}[x]_0
$$
so again
$$
[x]_0=[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1[x]_2
$$
and there is no contradiction.

So, to recap: $[R_2]_1^1$ has as columns the coordinate expressions of $\mathcal{B}_2$ in $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $[R_1]_0^0$ has as columns the coordinate expressions of $\mathcal{B}_1$ in $\mathcal{B}_0$. Therefore, applying $[R_2]_1^1$ to $[x]_2$ gives the expression of $x$ in $\mathcal{B}_1$ and then applying $[R_1]_0^0$ to $[x]_1$ gives the expression of $x$ in $\mathcal{B}_0$

I think you approach this pretty much in anyway, though, as long as you keep a sharp distinction between a linear transformation and a matrix and make sure you always know what exact coordinate matrix your linear transformation has and in which basis you've decided to express it.

EDIT:
eyeballfrog's answer says that the correct way is $v_0=R_2R_1v_2$. You also said in your question that obviously, $R_2R_1\neq R_1R_2$. So the answers we provided seem inconsistent. However, consider that both
$$
[x]_0=[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1[x]_2
$$
and
$$
[x]_0=[R_2]_0^0[R_1]_0^0[x]_2
$$
In fact, $[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1=[R_2]_0^0[R_1]_0^0$, so if you don't use coordinate transformations carefully, it looks like we would have $R_1R_2=R_2R_1$ - however, if we use the $[\cdot]$ notation, the confusion disappears as the $R$'s represent rotations in different bases. So in fact both answers are correct, it just amounts to different coordinate expressions.

EDIT:
Also, what about defining $R_3=R_2R_1$, is everything still consistent? Well, since $R_3$ takes $\mathcal{B}_0$ to $\mathcal{B}_2$, we have $[R_3]_0^0=[\mathrm{Id}]_0^2=[\mathrm{Id}]_0^1[\mathrm{Id}]_1^2=[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1$. It looks like $R_1$ and $R_2$ have flipped - but this is actually just what needs to happen. Indeed, we already know the first equality in the following line:
$$
[R_1]_0^0[R_2]_1^1=[R_2]_0^0[R_1]_0^0=[R_2R_1]_0^0=[R_3]_0^0
$$
as required.

Comment: I am quite unsure about the difference between $[R_2]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_1^1$.
As **rotations** $[R_2]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_1^1$ describe the same rotation, their columns are $([x]_1, [y]_1, [z]_1) \implies [R_2]_0^0 = [R_2]_1^1$.
They do not operate a change the basis between input and output vectors. 
So we have $[a]_0 = [R_1^{-1}]_0^0 [R_2^{-1}]_0^0 [x]_0 = [R_1^{-1}]_0^0 [R_2^{-1}]_1^1 [a]_0$. 
However, to apply the rotation $[R_2^{-1}]_1^1$ on $[a]_0$, its basis has to be changed such that $[Id]_0^1 [R_2]_1^1 [Id]_1^0 = [R_2]_0^0 \neq [R_2]_1^1$.

Comment: Yet, as **change of basis**:  $[R_2]_1^1$ brings $[v]_2$ to $[R_2 v]_1$, so $[R_2]_1^1 = [Id]_1^2$. So even though their columns are the same, $[R_2]_0^0 \neq [Id]_1^2$.

Comment: $[R_2]_0^0$ has as columns the coordinate expressions of $R_2a,R_2b,R_2c$ in $\mathcal{B}_0$ while $[R_2]_1^1$ has as columns the coordinate expressions of $\mathcal{B}_2$ in $\mathcal{B}_1$, so I don't see how they could be the same.

Comment: Because as **rotations** $[R_2 a]_0 = R_2 [a]_0$, $[x]_1 = [R_2 i]_1 = R_2 [i]_1 = R_2 [a]_0 \implies [x]_1 = [R_2 a]_0 $. So the coordinate expression of $R_2 a$ in $\mathcal{B}_0$ is the coordinate expression of $x \in \mathcal{B}_2$ in  $\mathcal{B}_1$. Making a difference between $[R_2]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_1^1$ should implies that $R_2 [i]_1 \neq R_2 [a]_0$ because with your notation it is $[R_2]_1^1 [i]_1 \neq [R_2]_0^0 [a]_0$. Sorry your comment answer to a comment I deleted to reformulate it.

Comment: $[R_2]_1^1[i]_1\neq[R_2]_0^0[a]_0$ does not imply that $R_2[i]_1\neq R_2[a]_0$. As far as your first line goes, I don't understand what you mean by "as rotations". Yes, $R_1$ and $R_2$ give rotations. That does not mean that somehow $[R_2a]_0=R_2[a]_0$ but that $[R_2a]_0=[R_2]_0^0[a]_0$. Also, $[x]_1=[R_2i]_1=[R_2]_1^1[i]_1=[R_2]_1^1[a]_0$ so you can't conclude that $[x]_1=[R_2a]_0$.

Comment: I would be very happy if you wouldn't write things like $R_2[a]_0$. $[a]_0$ is a coordinate expression of a vector, $R_2$ is a matrix that acts on $\mathbb{R}^3$. No-one guaranteed that any of $\mathcal{B}_{0/1/2}$ are the standard $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ so writing things out like this, without $[]$, gets very confusing and might very well end up giving wrong results.

Comment: I think the problem is that you view $[R_2]_1^1$ and $[R_2]_0^0$ as somehow the same because they correspond to the same rotation, but they really aren't the same. There must be a difference between them: one expresses $R_2$ in one basis and the other expresses $R_2$ in another. They can't be the same, that would make no sense, of course $R_2$ looks different depending on what specific coordinates you pick. But $R_2$ itself is always the same. So: $[R_2]\neq R_2$ is my point. A rotation is simply not the same as its own coordinate expression; though of course they are intimately related.

Comment: I think i might finally get it, let's take the rotation of angle $\alpha$ around the axis defined by the vector $u$. In this case, $[R]_1^1 = R(\alpha,[u]_1)$ and $[R]_0^0 = R(\alpha,[u]_0)$. When composing rotations from a vector in $\mathcal{B_0}$ I have to use $[R_1]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_0^0$ compute the output vector in $\mathcal{B_0}$. Now, if the input vector is in $\mathcal{B_1}$ I have to use  $[R_1]_1^1$ and $[R_2]_1^1$.  Is that right ?

Comment: Firstly, your comment made me realize that $[R^{-1}]\neq[R]^T$ all the time, only (I think) if the basis is orthonormal. But luckily this isn't a problem as you can replace ^T everywhere with ^{-1} which is more general. Also your $[R]_1^1=R(\alpha,[u]_1)$ example might (again, not sure, but it looks a bit fishy) break down if $\mathcal{B}_1$ isn't orthogonal... But your second comment is correct - if your input vector is expressed in $\mathcal{B}_0$ you use $[R]_0^0$ and if it's in $\mathcal{B}_1$ you use $[R]_1^1$. And the output is then again interpreted to be in the same basis.

Comment: However, because your bases are defined by invoking these rotations, it also turns out that you can use the matrices $[R_1]_0^0$ and $[R_2]_1^1$ to move between bases, so these matrices can do several things at once - they both represent the rotation in a fixed basis and the $[\mathrm{Id}]_0^1$ things which represent "identity" between different bases, i.e. keeping the vector itself the same but changing bases. And this is basically the difference between active and passive transformations.

Comment: Rotations matrices are orthogonal, so I also think that the basis has to be orthogonal too. Yet, it was just an illustration to highlight the difference between the two matrices $[R]_0^0$ and $[R]_1^1$. It is now clear for me and the problem is solved. Thank you very much for your answers and your patience.

Comment: No problem, I know that figuring this out can be pretty mind-bending at times, I had a lot of trouble with this particular issue in a course last year. Thank you too for the discussion!

Comment: I think a lot of confusion came from the fact that I considered the example of two successive rotation in a plane. And it that specific case we have $[R]_1^1 =[R]_0^0$.

Comment: Yeah, 2D is a bit "too simple" sometimes, also for example rotations in 2D commute but of course that isn't true in any higher dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here
$$
v_0 = R_1 v_1\\
v_1 = R_2 v_2
$$

$R_1$ as a matrix is expressed in terms of basis $\mathcal B_0$, while $R_2$ as a matrix is expressed in basis $\mathcal B_1$. In order to use matrix multiplication to do this problem, they need to be expressed in the same basis. The rotation $R_2$ expressed as a matrix in basis $\mathcal B_0$ is $R_1^{-1}R_2R_1$. So instead of $v_0 = R_1 R_2 v_2$, you get
$$
v_0 = R_1(R_1^{-1}R_2R_1)v_2 = R_2 R_1 v_2
$$
and there is no contradiction.

Comment: **1)** So in the case of rotations $R_1$ and $R_2$ are linear applications of $\mathbb{R}^3$ expressed in $\mathcal{B}_0$, while in the case of changes of basis $R_1$ and $R_2$ are transformations "unrelated" to the rotations. Even though the matrices components are the same, the meaning is different, right ?

**2)**  "$R_1$ as a matrix is expressed in terms of basis $\mathcal{B}_0$", because columns are the vectors of $\mathcal{B}_1$ expressed in $\mathcal{B}_0$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this reasoning. If we accept that $v_0 = R_1 v_1$ and $v_1=R_2v_2$ then it immediately follows that $v_0=R_1R_2v_2$ since these are all just column vectors of three numbers and $3\times 3$ matrices. I think that $v_0=R_1R_2v_2$ is correct and $v_0=R_2R_1v_2$ is not, since the argument for this second part relies on the fact that $a_0=x_2$ but this does not imply $x_0=R_2R_1 x_2$ just because $x=R_2R_1 a$

Comment: Or maybe we're all saying the same thing but not enough care is being taken to differentiate between $R_1$ and $R_2$ as rotations and $R_1$ and $R_2$ viewed as coordinate transformations.

Comment: @J_P $v_0=R_2 R_1 v_2$ is definitely the correct one, as $R_3 = R_2 R_1$ is the total rotation matrix, whose columns are the coordinates of $\mathcal{B}_2$ vectors in $\mathcal{B}_0$ basis, which is the definition of the matrix associated to the change of basis $\mathcal{B}_0$ to $\mathcal{B}_2$. As suggested by the answer, I guess that indeed not enough care was taken to make the difference between rotations and change of basis. However I commonly found in several courses the incorrect formula I highlighted in my question, so composition of change of basis has to be done very carefully.

Comment: $R_3=R_2R_1$ may be the total rotation matrix, but that does not mean that the coordinate transformation is $R_2R_1$ - in fact, it is the transpose of this: $(R_2R_1)^T$. I'll try to write up an answer of my own. Now I may very well be incorrect but I think it can't hurt to discuss this.

Comment: Or should I say, $R_3=R_2R_1$ is the total linear transformation, but the actual coordinate matrix of $R_3$ is not the right matrix to take, we need its transpose.

Comment: @J_P As I am French, we maybe also have a problem of terminology. In my courses, a change of basis matrix $P_{\mathcal{B}_0,\mathcal{B}_1}$ allows to express a vector $v$ coordinates in $\mathcal{B}_0$ from coordinates in $\mathcal{B}_1$ such that $v_0 = P_{\mathcal{B}_0,\mathcal{B}_1} v_1$. The columns of $P_{\mathcal{B}_0,\mathcal{B}_1}$  are $\mathcal{B}_1$ vectors coordinates in $\mathcal{B}_0$. Even though the notation used in France suggests the opposite. That said, I am pretty sure that $R_3$ is also the correct matrix to use, **with that notation**.

Comment: I think we use the same notation. Maybe think of it just in $2D$ with a 90 degree rotation, if you take the $x$-axis to the $y$-axis: the actual rotation is $R$, but to transform from the first basis to the other you need $R^T$, maybe look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation

Comment: Ok, so now take the coordinate vector of $x=(1,0)^T$ in $(i,j)$; it's $x_1=(0,-1)^T$, while $x_0=(1,0)^T$. But $x_1\neq Rx_0$; however, $x_1=R^Tx_0$.

Comment: @J_P Let's consider 2D with a 90 degree rotation and define the basis $(i,j)$ as the rotation of $(x,y)$ by $R$. So $i = (0,1)^T = y$ and $j = (-1,0)^T = -x$. Here $i$ and $j$ are expressed in the canonical basis $(x,y)$. A vector $v = (v_x, v_y)$ becomes $v' = Rv = (v_x', v_y') = (-v_y, v_x)^T$ in $(x,y)$ basis _Active_ .  The vector $v$ is expressed in basis $(i,j)$ as $(v_y, -v_x )^T = R^T v$ . So if $\mathcal{B}_1 = (i,j)$ and $\mathcal{B}_0 = (x,y)$ we have $v_0 = (v_x,v_y)^T$ and $v_1 = (v_y, -v_x )^T$, so $v_0 = R v_1$. And we have $v_1 = R^T v_0$ _Passive_.  I don't see any problem.

Comment: Right, so for two rotations you have $v_2=R_2^Tv_1=R_2^TR_1^Tv_0$ so $v_0=R_1R_2v_2$ and that is not $R_2R_1v_2$. Also, suppose you had $100$ rotations and it were the case that $v_0=R_{100}...R_{1}v_{100}$. Isn't it a bit odd that the transformation between bases $0$ and $1$ is applied to a vector expressed in basis $100$?

Answer (score 0):

In order to illustrate the answers, I made a small Matlab code corresponding to the three successive rotations corresponding to the classical Euler angles (precession, nutation and intrinsic rotation). It shows clearly the link between the active and passive transformations.

**Illustration**

```
% ---------------- First rotation: Precession around Oc axis 

a_0 = [1,0,0]';
b_0 = [0,1,0]';
c_0 = [0,0,1]';

R1_00 = rotmat(20*pi/180,c_0); % 

% ---------------- Second rotation: Nutation around Oi axis

i_0 = R1_00*a_0;
j_0 = R1_00*b_0;
k_0 = R1_00*c_0;

R2_00 = rotmat(40*pi/180,i_0);      
R2_11 = rotmat(40*pi/180,[1,0,0]');

% Comparison (they are equals)
R2_00
[R2_00*a_0 R2_00*b_0 R2_00*c_0]
R1_00*R2_11*inv(R1_00)

% ---------------- Third rotation: % Intrinsic rotation around 0z axis
% Basis 2
x_0 = R2_00*i_0;
y_0 = R2_00*j_0;
z_0 = R2_00*k_0;

R3_00 = rotmat(15*pi/180,z_0) 
R3_22 = rotmat(15*pi/180,[0,0,1]')

% Comparison (they are equals)
R3_00
[R3_00*a_0 R3_00*b_0 R3_00*c_0]
R1_00*(R2_11*R3_22*inv(R2_11))*inv(R1_00)

% Basis 3 from successive rotation (active transformation)
e_0 = R3_00*x_0;
f_0 = R3_00*y_0;
g_0 = R3_00*z_0;

% Basis 3 from successive change of basis (passive transformation)
e_0_bis = R1_00*R2_11*R3_22*a_0;
f_0_bis = R1_00*R2_11*R3_22*b_0;
g_0_bis = R1_00*R2_11*R3_22*c_0;

% Comparison (their are equals)
[e_0 e_0_bis]
[f_0 f_0_bis]
[g_0 g_0_bis]
```

**Rotation matrix function 'rotmat'**

```
function R = rotmat(theta,u)
u_x = u(1);
u_y = u(2);
u_z = u(3);

R = [cos(theta) + (u_x^2)*(1 - cos(theta)), u_x*u_y*(1-cos(theta))-u_z*sin(theta), u_x*u_z*(1-cos(theta)) + u_y*sin(theta);
     u_y*u_x*(1-cos(theta))+u_z*sin(theta),cos(theta) + (u_y^2)*(1 - cos(theta)), u_y*u_z*(1-cos(theta)) - u_x*sin(theta);
     u_z*u_x*(1-cos(theta))-u_y*sin(theta), u_z*u_y*(1-cos(theta))+u_x*sin(theta), cos(theta) + (u_z^2)*(1 - cos(theta))];
end
```

So, to conclude on this question, it is of crucial importance to be careful about the meaning of each matrix and the basis in which it is defined.